# intellij IDEA: unknown function in SASS file

Tags: intellij-idea, sass

I am working with Buefy/Bulma and Vue-CLI 3.

I get an unknown function inspection info on the SASS function `findColorInvert(...)` that I import from the bulma utilities.

I have `@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all"` at the top of my scss file which imports `functions.sass`:

```css
...    
@function findColorInvert($color)
  @if (colorLuminance($color) > 0.55)
    @return rgba(#000, 0.7)
  @else
    @return #fff
...
```

Here IntelliJ doesn't even recognize the variable `$color`in the function body. Let alone `colorLuminance`, which is a function defined in the same file.

I have the proper file types set (`settings/Editor/File Types: SassStyleSheet:*sass` and `SCSSStyleSheet:*scss`).

When I compile, the correct CSS is generate and I get no error from the CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node_modules/bulma` is excluded from indexing because it's not listed as a project direct dependency after installing `buefy`, so functions defined there can't be resolved. Marking it as *Not Excluded* (right-click the folder, **Mark directory as/Cancel exclusion**) should fix the issue

[image]